# AWS Cloud Quest API Error in all regions except Virginia

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm using AWS Cloud quest as a teaching tool and to get the badge "AWS Cloud Quest: Cloud Practitioner" but.... I'm already stuck on the second mission due to an aws error.
The exercise consists of creating two ECS instances, one in the Northern Virgina region and the other in any different region. After starting the mission, the AWS console opens with a user that is created automatically, like this:
[image]

The problem is that you can only create the instance in the Virginia region because any other region fails in internal services:
[image]

[image]

The errors are present for ALL regions except Virgina and I cannot alter the user permissions because it is created automatically by the AWS Cloud Quest platform.

Have you come across this problem? Do you have any idea how to bypass it?

Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 2):

To create a second instance in a new Avaiability Zone, just select a different subnet of the subnet choosed in the first instance it the VPC section , as the figure shows: [image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message and after a while of observing what could have caused the problem I realised I actually did not follow the right instruction. Instead of inputting the ec2 instance ID of i-xxxxxxxxxx I rather entered the name of the ec2 instance reason I got the error message.
Also remember the two ec2 instances are in the same region us-east-1 but different AZs.
Thanks

Comment: Incredible ... re-read n times, I had not noticed the thing. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The region restriction is there *by design*. You're only allowed to create resources in *one region* and that has to do with the `IAM` role that's being generated by `AWS`.

In other words, you cannot bypass it.

If you want to create resources in other regions, you'd have to open your own `AWS` account.

Comment: I had already thought of such a solution but I believe that AWS Cloud Quest platform works exclusively with user that is created spot. From the mission validation page, I tried to validate the following EC2 instances: 

* i-070bed462dc4d3dbb (AWSLabsUser in AZ Virginia)

* i-01d979163b854a1a3 (personal account in AZ Oregon)

but the result is the following:

"VALIDATION FAILED. COULD NOT FIND AN INSTANCE WITH ID i-01d979163b854a1a3."

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, an Availability Zone and a Region are two different things:

- AWS has the concept of a Regions, which are physical locations around the world where they cluster data centers
- A Region can have multiple Availability Zones
- An Availability Zone (AZ) is one OR MORE discrete data centers with redundant power, networking, and connectivity in an AWS Region

So.. for your specific question. By the time of writing, the Northern Virgina region (**us-east-1**) has 2 Availability Zones: **us-east-1a** AND **us-east-1b**. You choose them by selecting the correct subnet.